# Can't Get jQuery Validation Plugin Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble getting jQuery's validation plugin to work. I'm pulling in both jquery.js and the jquery.validate.js successfully. My script is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#apply").validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: "required",
            surname: "required",

            secret: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            verify_secret: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5,
                equalTo: "#secret"
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },

        },
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
            surname: "Please enter your surname",

            secret: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            verify_secret: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",

        }
    });


});
```

Here's my markup:

```
    <form method="post" action="apply.php" id='apply'>


        <input type='text' name='firstname' id='firstname' value=''/>
        <input type='text' name='surname' id='surname' value=' '/>

<input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='Your Email Address'/>

        <label for='secret'>Your Chosen Password</label>
        <input type='password' name='secret' id='secret'/>

        <label for='verify_secret'>Verify Your Password</label>
        <input type='password' name='verify_secret' id='verify_secret'/>



        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
    </form>
```

Is there some dependency I'm missing? I'm getting no error messages or anything else that might help me fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As per jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), `$().ready(function() {` is "***not*** recommended".

Since you mention nothing about other JavaScript libraries also using the `$` variable on your page, or anything about using [noConflict() mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), just use the standard `document.ready` function *without* passing the superfluous `$` into it.

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

Here is a working demo of your code...

**http://jsfiddle.net/9ZVab/**

I also found/removed a couple of trailing commas.  I noticed you have the same rules on both password fields.  Since the second field is using the `equalTo` rule, the other rules are redundant and could be removed.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/tnuQa/

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely. And thanks for clearing up the matter of the superfluous $.

Answer (score 1):

instead of this , i cant understand why you used jquery like this ?

```
$().ready(function($) {
```

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: That was how the ready handler was supplied in the plugin demo. If I don't pass $ as an argument to the function, I get an error stating that $(...).validate() is not a function. Found another post stating that you may need to pass $ when using this plugin.

Comment: @Dio, you do not need to pass a `$` into the function unless you are using `noConflict()` mode.  There is nothing special about the Validate plugin in that regard, so what you read is either false or you misunderstood.